# body background css fixation

Tags: css

I want to give my body a background that is fixed in the middle.

So that when I shrink my window it won't start cutting the right-side and keeping the left side static. I want it to cut left and right at the same time.

I want it to be like this example: www.everythingisnew.pt

In that website you can clearly see that the background gets "eaten" by the window at the same time from both sides.

What is the css behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `background-position: center` in your `body` element's CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('your/background/src.png') no-repeat fixed center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem

```
background-image: url(src.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: fixed center;
background-size: cover;
```